# Нужны книги по Unity для написания теоретической части курсача

Tags: unity3d, книги

У меня тема на курсовую работу : " Разработка компьютерной игры в Unity ". 
Саму игру уже сделал , вполне хватило одного видеоурока и документации для моей задумки , но в курсач еще входит еще теоретическая часть (90% которого простая вода). 
Посоветуйте книги по Unity , которые есть в свободном доступе , язык не особо важен, интересует только вступление и описание самого Unity.

Comment: https://unity3d.com/ru/

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/34792570/
https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/137562957/
https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/34867953/
https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/27711604/
https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/138275843/
https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/138275846/

Я верю в то, что вы пойдёте и закажете их, либо купите в электронном виде. Для того, чтобы найти где их можно получить - спрашивайте у гугла. Знать, каким образом вы получите информацию из этих книг мне совсем не обязательно.
Пользуйтесь :)